# Alternatives to "enthusiasm declined"?

Tags: word-usage

I'd like to say something like "My enthusiasm declined after I read the news", but I'm not sure *decline* goes well with *enthusiasm*. Is there a better alternative? Or is *decline* just fine?

Comment: How about "My zeal zeroed out after I read the news"?

Comment: _Zeal_ doesn't quite work in the context I'm considering.

Comment: Then I'd recommend Bill F's "My enthusiasm waned". Better than "declined".

Comment: Off topic: writing advice request. Please read the [FAQ] before posting.

Comment: Hmm, I wasn't sure _declined_ could actually be used here, and thought asking whether it could or could not would be appropriate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Declined" is a verb that is often used with numbers, eg the stock market declined. To my ears, it sounds out of place.

I would suggest "sank" or "waned" or "deflated".

Comment: Thanks. I did a search on Google for "enthusiasm ...", it looks like the ordering of the frequencies is _waned_ > _deflated_ > _declined_ > _sank_, with _waned_ having a clear lead (twenty-fold higher in frequency than _deflated_).

Answer (score 0):

Why not “I *lost interest* in the movie after I read the reviews.”

Answer (score 0):

> My interest died after I read the news

Comment: Please don't use the number 1 when you want to write a capital letter "i".

Answer (score 0):

My interest decreased after I read the news.

Comment: This is a site for proper use of English. If you give an answer, please try to use correct spelling.